# Cómo permitir accesos a páginas en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, permisos

Tengo una duda existen la posibilidad de dar acceso o restringir acceso a una vista sin usar componentes como Shinobi y spetie de roles y permisos? Y si es así como se lograría?

Comment: Claro, para eso existen por ejemplo los Gates, has tratado algo?, Tu pregunta es muy amplia y va a terminar cerrada

Comment: Aquí tienes la respuesta https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#gates

Comment: O construye un sistema de sesiones con las herramientas propias de PHP, las opciones son variadas, ya depende de ti